# How to push to a map value array and use it as state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have the following state in React:

```js
const [tasksMap, setTasksMap] = useState(new Map());
```

with the following map creation:

```js
tasks.forEach((task) => {
  const key = `${week.year}-${week.weekNo}`;

  if (!tasksMap.has(key)) {
    tasksMap.set(key, []);
  }
  tasksMap.get(key).push(task);
});
```

How can I set the map `tasksMap` as the React state?

`setTasksMap(tasksMap.set(key, []));` works but has an empty array as value, which does not update when I run `tasksMap.get(key).push(task);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Here I used `separate variable` to store data and set that variable into the `state` at last.

```
let mapObj = new Map();

tasks.forEach((task) => {
  const key = `${week.year}-${week.weekNo}`;

  if (!mapObj.has(key)) {
    mapObj.set(key, []);
  }
  mapObj.get(key).push(task);
});

setTasksMap(mapObj);
```